# What is the difference between using Django's APIClient from a unit test or from a Django shell

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am trying to write unit tests for an Django OAuth2 API. I am using Django's APIClient library. if I use it from a Django shell. it works perfectly, but if I use is in a unit test, the POST request to the view returns a 401 error: {"error": "invalid_client"}

```py
[ EDITED ]
### This works perfectly in a Django Shell

from rest_framework.test import APIClient
client = APIClient()
response = client.post('/authentication/register/', {"username": "testuser9", "password": "1234abcd"},
header={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

[ EDITED ]
### This unit test fails with a 401

class OAuth2TestCase(APITestCase):

    def test_user_registration_valid_data(self):
        """Tests register view"""
        client = APIClient()
        response = client.post('/authentication/register/', 
        {"username": "testuser88", "password": "1234abcd"},
          header={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

[ EDITED ]
### The view

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def register(request):
    '''
    Registers user to the server. Input should be in the format:
    {"username": "username", "password": "1234abcd"}
    '''

    serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    logger.info("Request Data {}".format(request.data))
    if serializer.is_valid():

        serializer.save()

        data={
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'username': request.data['username'],
            'password': request.data['password'],
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        }
        test_request = HttpRequest()
        test_request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        test_request.POST = data
        test_request.method = 'POST'
        test_request.META = request.META
        test = TokenView()
        test_response = test.post(request=test_request)
        return test_response

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What are the differences between making the `APIClient` request from the Django shell and making it from a unit test?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing here. Is your view making an actual HTTP POST request back to the same site? Why? If so, it explains your problem; presumably in your test you don't actually run a server, so the request will fail. APIClient simulates a request, it doesn't actually make one or expect a real server to be running. But the solution is not to do this at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The view takes in a POST request with a username and password from a user and then sends a POST request with this information along with other application data to the OAuth2 Authorization server in order to get the access token. The user also must be created in the on that authorization server before the POST request to that server is made in order for it to respond with the access code. This view is part of a Django application which is acting as a client to this Authorization/Authentication server. This Django application is supposed to handle post requests from mobile clients

Comment: I still don't understand. Is the oauth2 server a separate thing? If so why is it running on 127.0.0.1:8000? That's surely the address of the Django dev server. Surely both the oauth and the mobile app are part of the same Django project?

Comment: The ``oauth2_provider`` is an installed app in the Django project, not something I built myself. The Django project I'm building is an application registered to the the OAuth2 provider. It acts an intermediary between the requests from the mobile client and the OAuth2 Application.

Comment: I wasn't asking whether you built it yourself. It is another endpoint in the same Django project, so as I said you are posting back to the same site which a) will not work unless you run the dev server and b) is not a sensible thing to do. Instead, you should have integrated the registration code with your register endpoint.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay, I see now what you mean, my bad. Could you please explain what you mean by "integrated the registration code with your register endpoint" - I don't really get this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think I understand what you mean now, and have changed my view accordingly. This now works without running the application on the dev server. Please see the edited question as the unit test is still failing. Thank you for the help!